# What is best practice for images in mid fidelity designs?

Tags: image, best-practice, prototype, image-format

Can a mid-fi design have photos or do they absolutely have to be image place holders?
Can black and white photos be used?

Any resources about convention for mid-fi images is helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Mid-fi is where you start getting closer to the product/website design vision without going into pixel-perfect detail (hifi). It's a good place to start showing an example of what kind of images will support the design.

Comment: Thanks @Stacy H , that is what I wanted to hear. However, when I research mid-fi I keep seeing image place holders and some youtube 'guides' saying that mid-fi should be black and white. What you are saying makes more sense.

Comment: I should mention that mid-fi images are still optional -- you can choose them during hifi. But should examples be allowed in mid-fi? I believe so.